# Can't retrieve CKRecords to resolve conflicts on CKErrorCodeServerRecordChanged in CKModifyRecordsOperation

Tags: cloudkit

I ran into some problem when trying to handle errors when doing batch operations on records in CloudKit.

I am successfully extracting the dictionary containing the partial errors, which I can iterate over. However, I am not able to get the records needed to resolve the conflict for CKErrorCodeServerRecordChanged. According to the docs I should be able to get 3 records out of the dictionary:

- CKRecordChangedErrorServerRecordKey
- CKRecordChangedErrorAncestorRecordKey
- CKRecordChangedErrorClientRecordKey

Thank you for any hints on what I am doing wrong here.

```
func pushRecordChangesForZoneID(recordZoneID: CKRecordZoneID) {
// ...
modifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        if error.code == CKErrorCode.PartialFailure.rawValue {
            if let errorDict = error.userInfo?[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey] as? [CKRecordID : NSError] {
                for (recordID, partialError) in errorDict {
                    if partialError.code == CKErrorCode.ServerRecordChanged.rawValue {
                        if let userInfo = partialError.userInfo {
                            let serverRecord = userInfo[CKRecordChangedErrorServerRecordKey] as? CKRecord
                            // serverRecord will always be nil
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Additional information: When I print the description of the userInfo dict of the partial error (partialError.userInfo) it doesn’t look like it contains the other CKRecords:

```
[NSDebugDescription: CKInternalErrorDomain: 2037, NSLocalizedDescription: Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x7fb41bf7e640; DA39FE08-AB0B-4F07-A42E-F5732B114706:(userData:__defaultOwner__)> to server: Protection data didn't match, NSUnderlyingError: <CKError 0x7fd89a92d370: "Unknown Error" (2037)>]
```

The description of the source error's dictionary (errorDict) looks like this (and I can successfully get the dictionary containing the recordIDs and partial errors out via CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey):

```
[<CKRecordID: 0x7fb5bb88afa0; C1575083-F992-448A-8D77-D62C4A42D696:(userData:__defaultOwner__)>: <CKError 0x7fb5b961c6a0: "Batch Request Failed" (22/2024); server message = "Atomic failure"; uuid = 1E4C0FD5-EC10-4071-B277-102A9F1B0E5E; container ID = "iCloud.net.neverthesamecolor.atsumeru">, <CKRecordID: 0x7fb5bb848ad0; DA39FE08-AB0B-4F07-A42E-F5732B114706:(userData:__defaultOwner__)>: <CKError 0x7fb5b9653060: "Server Record Changed" (14/2037); "Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x7fb41bd9ca50; DA39FE08-AB0B-4F07-A42E-F5732B114706:(userData:__defaultOwner__)> to server: Protection data didn't match">]
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. This is a bug I think. The only workaround left is to fetch the record from the server using the CKRecordID returned in the userInfo dictionary. Make changes to that record and then use it to save it to the server.

Comment: Good to hear I am not the only one with this problem. But fetching the CKRecords that have a conflict is a solution I'd like to avoid. This would mean a lot of additional network requests which would otherwise not be necessary. I requested technical support at Apple for this issue now.

Comment: Well I have solved it the same way by fetching the CKRecords with conflicts. Awesome Let me know what you learn from them !

Comment: btw looks like you are trying to work out the syncing part in CloudKit. Check out https://github.com/CloudKitSpace/CKSIncrementalStore

Comment: Since the result of the support request was that no workaround exists for this issue, I filed a bug report.

Comment: You did the right thing :)

Comment: Same Here. Does anyone have a report bug number ?

Comment: Report 21497003. I reposted in Open Radar: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5506295108993024

Answer (score 0):

The docs say it's a custom zone feature only.

Edit 21st Jan 2016: It's working for me right now even in the default zone and public database. This is a big change from before.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explicitly say it. I am actually working with a custom zone, but it is not working.